# PHP in_array issue while checking zero value in array giving true

Tags: php

I am facing one strange situation while working with PHP's in_array(). Below is my code and its output

```
<?php
$process = array("as12"=>"deleted","as13"=>1,"as14"=>1);
if(!in_array(0, $process))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "not success";

//It's outputting "not success";

var_dump(in_array(0, $process));
//Output : null

var_dump(in_array(0, $this->tProcessActions) === true);
///Output : true
```

If we look at the `$process` array, there is no `0` value in it. Still it's giving me true if I check `if(in_array(0, $process))`

Can anybody has idea about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need *strict* checks, use the *`$strict`* option:

```
in_array(0, $process, true)
```

PHP's string ⟷ int comparison is well known to be complicated if you don't know the rules/expect the wrong thing.

Comment: By putting `true` last parameter solved an issue. I seen it before long time and forgot to add when there is a mixed values in array like you said `string-int`

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
if(!in_array('0', $process)) {
```

or you can use search(optional) like

```
if(array_search('0',$process)) {
```

Comment: +1 from me. Yes. You're right. But why I need to put `0` in Quotes? If I search for 1 without Quotes then it's giving correct result.

Comment: Because `0 == "deleted"` using loose comparison. Note the third parameter to `in_array`, which forces strict comparison. Also have a look at the [type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should put `0` inside the quotes:

if(!in_array("0", $process))

Answer (score 1):

using the `strict` parameter gives what you want here:

```
$process = array("as12"=>"deleted","as13"=>1,"as14"=>1);
var_dump( in_array(0, $process, true ) );
// gives false
```

or use `array_search` and test if non-false;

```
var key = array_search( 0, array( 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 0 ) );
// key is "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because in_array maybe not strict type check. because if you check

```
 if (0 == "deleted") echo "xx";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(!in_array('0', $process))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use third parameter [$is_strict] of in_array function.

```
in_array(0, $process, true)
```

The point is what any string after (int) conversion equal to 0. 
(int) "deleted" => 0. 
So in_array without strict mode is equal to "deleted" == 0 which true. When you use strict its equal to "deleted" === 0 which false.